# How to achieve an AFNetworking class to be singleton?

Tags: afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am using an AFNetworking library to perform asynchronous URL request operation and everything is working fine. But, I am instantiating AFNetworking object for every service request, I make. So, I want eliminate duplicate object creation for every URL request. How to achieve a class to be singleton?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged the question `afnetworking-2` I'll assume that is what you're using. There is a difference in what class you subclass to make a singleton.

In the case of AFNetworking 2.0 you want to subclass `AFHTTPSessionManager` and set your subclass up to provide a single shared instance. Typically you would name the subclass after the web service you're communicating with, e.g. `WebServiceClient`.

The header file (WebServiceClient.h) of your subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager` might look something like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AFHTTPSessionManager.h"

@interface WebServiceClient : AFHTTPSessionManager

+ (instancetype)sharedClient;

@end
```

Your implementation file (WebServiceClient.m) would be as follows:

```
#import "WebServiceClient.h"

static NSString * const WebServiceAPIBaseURLString = @"https://api.mywebservice.com/";

@implementation WebServiceClient

+ (instancetype)sharedClient {
    static WebServiceClient *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[WebServiceClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:WebServiceAPIBaseURLString]];
    });

    return _sharedClient;
}

@end
```

Using this subclass you can now obtain the shared instance of `WebServiceClient` with the following code:

```
WebServiceClient *client = [WebServiceClient sharedClient];
```

When you want to make a request, you can do something like this:

```
WebServiceClient *client = [WebServiceClient sharedClient];
[client GET:@"/path" parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

    // Code to be executed upon successful response.

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

    // Code to be executed on failure response.

}];
```

For more information you can also find examples included in the [AFNetworking source on GitHub](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/Example)